# Number of new predictors

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have a matrix $X$ which has columns $x_1, x_2, \dots x_n$.  I'd like to create some additional columns for interactions.  For instance $x_1^2, x_1x_2, \dots, x_1x_n, x_2^2, \dots, x_n^2$.

EDIT:  There would be no need to generate the same interaction term twice.  So if I've already generated $x_ix_j$ there is no need to generate $x_jx_i$.

I'd like to be able to count how many new columns I would generate through this process.  How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The number interaction with itself, i.e. of the form $x_i^2$ is $n$. And the number of ordered pairs $(x_i,x_j)$ such that $i\neq j$ is $n(n-1)$. Then the number of unordered pairs $(x_i,x_j)$ such that $i\neq j$ is $n(n-1)/2$. Hence required number of interactions$$=n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Comment: Not quite.  I would generate $x_1x_2$ on my first go around, which would mean I wouldn't need to generate $x_2x_1$ because it would be the same as $x_1x_2$.  So it is less than $n^2$.

Comment: ok. edited the answer likewise.

Comment: Ah yes!  A quick sketch corroborates this.  Thanks a lot!